# Spring: @Autowire exception with @ImportResource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have following classes :

```
package testpackage;

class InventoryService {
 ....
}

package testpackage;

class TransferService {
    private String localManifestPath;

    @Bean 
    public InventoryService inventoryService() {
        return new InventoryService();
    }

    public void setLocalManifestPath(String localManifestPath) {
        this.localManifestPath = localManifestPath;
    }

}

package testpackage;

@Configuration
@Import ({TransferService.class})
class AppConfig {
    @AutoWired
    InventoryService inventoryService;

    ............
}
```

With above code autowiring to inventoryService works perfectly, but I also want to call setManifestPath declared in TransferService. For that I created following TransferService.xml:

```
<bean id="TransferService" class="testPackage.TransferService">
     <property name="localManifestPath" value="/home/edword/abcd.xml" />
</bean>
```

and used @ImportResource in place of @Import but it is not autowiring InventoryService and throwing

```
"Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: testpackage.inventoryService".
```

AppConfig with @ImportResource:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource ({"classpath*:/WEB-INF/*/TransferService.xml"})
class AppConfig {
    @AutoWired
    InventoryService inventoryService;

    ............
}
```

I know I am doing something stupid, but not able to figure it out on my own. Please help me to find it out.

Comment: Are the getters and setters for inventoryService in place?

Comment: Your `TransferService` should be a `@Configuration` object now it is just another bean.

Comment: Try removing the (*) asterisks and giving a fully qualified name, "classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/TransferService.xml" - like you said, stupid, I know, but it fixed some of my problems.